# .csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Tags: docker

I built project in .net framework.
and I decided to run docker container.

when i built my project with docker i faced with this error

.csproj : error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.

Please give me help to solve this error

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved that could help others to reproduce your problem

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UA1N.jpg)Open Docker Desktop application

Go to Setting

Go to Docker Engine

Add DNS tag in setting configuration as below

"dns":["1.1.1.1","8.8.8.8"]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).